# Confusion with regards to the phrase "exactly one of the events occurs"

Tags: probability

Suppose we have events $A$ and $B$. We want to write the probability that **exactly one of the events $A,B$ occurs** in terms of $P(A),P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$ only

My thought: Since I want only one occurring, $A$ or $B$, we must find $P(A \cup B)$ which equals $P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.. However, on my answer sheet it says the answer is $P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B )$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Imagine the sample space. Suppose you flip two coins, $A$ is 
"at least one head" and $B$ is "at least one tail".

Comment: @Jimmy: Just use `**asterisks**` for **bold text**, you don't need to abuse TeX math formatting for this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$P(A\cup B)$ includes those outcomes where both events $A$ and $B$ occur.  We want to exclude this case, because if they both occur it is not *exactly one* occurring.  This undesirable case is exactly $P(A\cap B)$, so we need to subtract it, as $$P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: @Henry Yes, that's what Vadim means: $P(A\cup B)$ includes those outcomes where both events $A$ and $B$ occur (as well as those events where only one of $A$ or $B$ occurs). He just didn't mention the part in parentheses, since the OP already seemed to be aware of it.

Comment: @LarsH - I had missed *includes*

Answer (score 8):

As vadim123 mentions, $A\cup B$ includes the outcome where $A$ **and** $B$ happens so we must subtract these off. We have

$$\begin{align*}
P(A\cap B^C)+P(A^C \cap B)
&=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)\\\\
&=\left(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)\right)-P(A\cap B)\\\\
&=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A \cap B)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Is $\cdot^C$ really the conventional way of writing the complement of an event? That's a horrible convention, in particular when the events are named $A$, $B$ etc.. (Though by no means uniquely horrible; I'm looking at you, [$B = QTZ^T$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Generalized_Schur_decomposition)...) Why not write it $P(A\cap\not B)$ or $P(A\cap\neg B)$?

Comment: Well $\lnot B$ is *sometimes* used, but a distinct *set operation* is much preferred rather than overloading the *logical operation*. So various conventions use: $B^\mathrm c, B', \overline B, B^\complement$, and such to indicate complementation. @leftaroundabout

Comment: @Henry Your comment is correct and doesn't contradict anything in this answer.

Comment: @MarkS. - I had missed *includes*

Comment: @leftaroundabout For the complement I never found a widespread notation that I liked. For that specific case, though, I'd use $P(A \setminus B) + P(B \setminus A)$, which is standard. (However, the "intersection&complement" variant notation can be more readable in some contexts, I think.)

Comment: @chi I personally used ${}\setminus A$ for a complement in my scribbles: the universal set is implied before the setminus, just as $0$ is implied before the minus in $-x$.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is  $$P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)=$$

$$ P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap B)=$$

$$P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$$